# Updating a specific object data in my rtk asyncthunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am new to rtk and immer. I have a problem regarding updating my state with my redux. Lets say when I logging in my user, I will store my user's data in redux with these kind of structure:

```
data = {
    "user_profile" : {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "Token": "12345678"
  },
  "basic_information": {
    "primary_information": {
        "sex": "MALE",
        "age": 30,
        "photo": "test.png"
    }
  }
}
```

now when i will call my update api, then my api returns something like these updated values:

```
updated_data = {
    "user_profile" : {
    "name": "John Test",   
  },
  "basic_information": {
    "primary_information": {
        "sex": "FEMALE",
        "age": 27,
    }
  }
}
```

I want to update my current state based on my api update state values, but i want the token will remain and other data that i didnt update.

Here is what i did/tried with the asyncthunk rtk.
I have a slice:

```
export const updatePrimaryInformation = createAsyncThunk(
  "profile/primary_info",
  async (arg, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    const { body, headers } = arg;
    try {
      const updateRequest = await commonPutRequest({
        body,
        headers,
        url: "http://localhost:8000/api/accounts_app/primary_information",
      });
      if (updateRequest) {
        return updateRequest;
      } else {
        throw new Error(updateRequest.message);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return rejectWithValue(err.message);
    }
  }
);

// loading: 'idle' | 'pending' | 'succeeded' | 'failed'
    const initialState = {
      data: {},
      loading: "idle",
      message: "",
    };


const authenticateSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      //login
      .addCase(fetchUserLogin.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = "pending";
      })
      .addCase(fetchUserLogin.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = "succeeded";
        state.data = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(fetchUserLogin.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = "failed";
        state.message = action.payload;
      })
      //logout
      .addCase(logoutUser.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = "pending";
      })
      .addCase(logoutUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        return initialState;
      })
      .addCase(logoutUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = "failed";
        state.message = action.payload;
      })
      //updatePrimaryInfo
      .addCase(updatePrimaryInformation.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = "pending";
      })
      .addCase(updatePrimaryInformation.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = "succeeded";        
        state.data.basic_information.primary_information = action.payload.basic_information.primary_information;        
      })
      .addCase(updatePrimaryInformation.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = "failed";
        // state.message = action.payload;
      });
    // .addCase(userLogout, (state) => {
    //   return initialState;
    // });
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux or immer doesn't have this functionality out of the box.

It sounds like you want to do the `merge` operation from lodash. This merges two objects together by only inserting undefined keys.

You can install lodash or look at the function and reimplment it. Lodash also has partial imports.

```
      .addCase(fetchUserLogin.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = "succeeded";
        state.data = _.merge(action.payload, state.data);
      })
```

Comment: i got two data in my part.

Comment: i got it. the merge function must first be the state.data followed by my updated data to override my data objects